# Como eu seto as configurações no portlet de menu, que está "Embebido" ou "Runtime ADD" no Layout.tpl do Liferay?

Tags: layout, liferay

Olá,
Preciso de uma ajudinha,

colocar o menu automaticamente no layout e ele deve possuir umas configurações específicas... 
"Não pode ser no tema porque nem todas as páginas deve exibir o menu."

Já tentei esse código ele traz o menu mais não remove as bordas...

```
set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false'))
$theme.runtime("71_INSTANCE_abcd", '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
```

Já tentei esse também e esse código também não remove as bordas...

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false")
$theme.runtime("71_INSTANCE_efgh", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

As duas formas que mencionei funcionam dentro do tema,
porém,  as configurações de remover a borda e outras que setei não estão funcionaram.
EX:

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("root-layout-level", "4")
```

O código completo é esse e não funciona:

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("header-type", "none")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("root-layout-type", "relative")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("root-layout-level", "4")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("included-layouts", "all")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("nested-children", "true")
$theme.runtime("71_INSTANCE_abcd", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset() 

Também tentei assim e sem sucesso:
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('header-type', 'none'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('root-layout-type', 'relative'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('root-layout-level', '4'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('included-layouts', 'all'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('nested-children', 'true'))
$theme.runtime("71_INSTANCE_efgh", '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
```

O ambiente aqui é Liferay 61.ga3

Se não for possível teremos que configurar 209 páginas na mão.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Testa inverter, colocando a última linha no início, antes de todo o resto do código:

```
set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
```

Comment: Mudar a ordem não influenciou no resultado final. Ainda preciso de ajuda :(

mais mesmo assim obrigado1

Comment: Não funcionou :'( mesmo assim obrigado!